# Retrieving DynamoDB Items by Sort Key Prefix from Secondary Index with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm working on a DynamoDB data model where I have a table called "RequestGroup" with specific primary key (PK) and sort key (SK) attributes. I've also created a Global Secondary Index (GSI) named "ReversedRGIndex" to support a specific query pattern. It's basically an inverted index, that should allow me to query the SK as if it were a PK.

```
Table Structure:

Table Name: RequestGroup
Primary Key (PK):
    Attribute Name: PK
    Attribute Type: String (S)
Sort Key (SK):
    Attribute Name: SK
    Attribute Type: String (S)

Secondary Index:
Index Name: ReversedRGIndex
Index Key Schema:
    Partition Key (PK): SK
    Sort Key (SK): PK
```

**Problem Statement:**
I want to query this DynamoDB table using the ReversedRGIndex to retrieve all items where the SK attribute begins with "PR#". Each record has a PK, which looks like this: "RequestGroup#123456". The usual SK records in this table might have two different SKs: PR# or Metadata. I want to filter only the first one (something like.. begins_with "PR#"). Therefore, I'm not able to specify which PK I want, as I want all SKs with PR#, regardless of their PK.

**Current Approach:**
I made a simplification of the code to display below.

```
const { DynamoDBClient, QueryCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb");
const client = new DynamoDBClient({});

exports.GetAllRules = async () => {

    const params = {
      TableName: "RequestGroup",
      IndexName: 'ReversedRGIndex',
      KeyConditionExpression: "BEGINS_WITH(PK, :pk_begins_with_pr)",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":pk_begins_with_pr": {"S": "PR#"},
      },
    };

    const command = new QueryCommand(params);
    const result = await client.send(command);
};
```

**Alternatives I tried before:**
I tried playing around with the parameters. Like passing the ExpressionAttributeValues with only "#PR", using the SK instead of the PK, etc. However, I wasn't able to find a solution for that so far.

Comment: In the GSI, supply a constant value for the PK (e.g. 1) and the underlying table's PK as the GSI's SK. Then query the GSI on PK=1 and SK begins_with PR#.

Comment: Not sure if I followed. My main issue is that I can't specify the PK (RequestGroup#12345). That's why I need to filter only by the SK using the begins_with

Comment: Hopefully Leeroy's answer explains things in a little more detail (it's the same proposed solution), but add follow-up questions if not.

Answer (score 1):

In DynamoDB you must always provide the full value of the partition key, regardless of you are querying from a base table or index.

In your case you are using begins_with on the partition key which will not work. An alternative approach is this:

| GSIPK | PK |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | PR#123 |
| 1 | PR#236 |
| 1 | metadata#001 |

This way you define a static value as your Partition key for the index, allowing you to do begins_with on the sort key and get all the items back.